# Eclipse C++ Hello World Program "Error starting process."

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm new to programming and decided to learn C++. I just learned the Hello World program and I tried to program it myself. I installed Eclipse C++ and GCC compiler like this video showed me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln1l8qSOBW0. I set the path to the C++.exe program in the bin section of the GCC folder in the C Drive. I just keep getting:

> "Launching FirstProgram Debug" has encountered a problem . Error starting process.

no matter where I choose the path.

I installed the GCC in `C:\Users\user\gcc` , yet I do not know what to do run the project correctly. I am able to build the program.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there anything in the error log? Window -> Show View -> Error Log

Comment: Possibly, your code is faulty, could you post your code here?

Comment: Also, is there anything else that is specified in the error? Or is it just what you specified above?

Comment: 'Launching FirstProgram Debug' has encountered a problem. Error starting process.

Comment: Code: #include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
 cout <<"Hello, World!\n";
 return 0;

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted in your comment is incorrect for 2 reasons:

**Firstly**, your header file should be:

```
    #include <iostream> // not std_lib_facilities.h
```

This header files is the standard header file included in all programs of c++. Its full name is input/output stream, and as the name suggests, it holds *family of class templates and supporting functions in the C++ Standard Library that implement stream-based input/output capabilities* (Obtained from: [Input/output (C++)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_(C%2B%2B)#Input.2Foutput_streams))

**Secondly**, the line that produces output has an error: `cout` does not have `std::` attached to it. The `std::` tag tells the compiler that the function `cout` is a part of the namespace std. To fix this you can either add `std::` before `cout`, or you can include the line:

```
 using namespace std;
```

just in between the `include` statement and the `int main()` line.

---

In the case that this does not fix the issue, then there could be something wrong in the way you have installed eclipse or the gcc compiler. In that case, I would recommend you to watch this video on YouTube: [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers - Download, Install, and Run | eitlearning.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dceXWafU1Z4). Note that this video is for a Windows Operating System.

This video takes you over the entire process of installing eclipse and its requisites. You can compare your installation process to the way the user in the video has done it to see if you missed a step or if you did something wrong.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the code error. I used the code give to me from Bjarnes Stroustrup, the creator of C++. I read the book: Programming: Principles and Practice using C++, 2nd edition. I will check the video anyways thank you and I will reply to tell you if it worked.

Comment: Typically, we use `iostream` and I wrote my first program, which was also "_Hello, World_" by the way, and I frankly never had, or have, used the library you mentioned above. That's why I just provided the more used alternative. Good luck with the video!

Comment: Thank you very much! The video didn't SOLVE the problem but it helped me HAVE it solved. It was something to do with the path of the compiler or something I think I mixed up the PATH and the C/C++ application. I got the program running, after a whole day of trying haha. But I encountered another problem. I would like to modify the output from Hello, World to Programming, Here I Go as the book suggested me. However, I keep getting Hello, World in the console. Could you help me modify the code? I built the new code first then ran it but it always outputs Hello World.

Comment: Snce c++ is a low level language, you need to save the code before running it, and you have to build the file. Have you done these 2 things?

Comment: Also, please select the tick mark next to my answer. It should turn green when you do so.

Comment: I tried to save it but it both save and save as buttons are un-pressable (is that a word?) but yeah I can't press them. And I clicked the green check mark.

Comment: And what is a ''low level language''? I thought C++ was one of the most powerful languages to learn when creating programs.

Comment: No, it means that it is closer to an assembly level language compared to, say, python. Also, try this link: [click here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html). Move to 2.1 step 1 and follow those steps. Honestly, I am not sure how eclipse runs as I have not used it (I use codeblocks and clion), but the site link I provided ives clear explainations as to how you should run your first program in c++. Try it out, and tell me whether it works.

Comment: Ah I see. Well anyways thank you for your help. My mistake was actually a bunch of mistakes. First, my code was wrong. The #include "std_lib_facilities.h" is only correct if you HAVE that header file. Therefore, I couldn't build my project properly, therefore no .exe was created. When no .exe is created, I can't run anything since there is nothing to run. Plus, in the run configurations, in the C/C++ Applications I chose the folder of my compiler. I have no idea why I did that. Anyways thank you very much you have been very helpful.

Comment: I see. I frankly never used the `"std_lib_facilities.h` file, so I did not know about it. Good luck in the future!